# length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have a .Net Web service (.asmx) which will return a Json string to my client. However, some of my data is really large and I get this error occasionally.

> The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

I've changed the maxJsonLength property to 2147483644, but it still doesn't work. Please help... Thank you.

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>



[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void GetData(string login)
        {
            // throw an error on this line...
            string result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(service.GetData(login));


            Context.Response.Write(result);
        }
```

Comment: Does [this question (and its answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config) resolve your issue?

Comment: George - the second answer in the link from @NextInLine is the one you want: set `maxJsonLength` as a property on your `new JavaScriptSerializer`. The first answer in the link won't help you.

Comment: You say you are using ["Newtonsoft.Json"](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), but in your code you are using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Just to confirm, you're not using Newtonsoft.Json, right?

Comment: @dbc: Yes you are right. I am not using Newtonsoft Json for this case. I was used it for another method.  I am sorry for the confusing. I will update my question. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Ed Gibbs: Hi Ed, Thank you.  Your suggestion works!  I used the second one.

Comment: Glad to hear it George. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to Ed Gibbs and @NextInLine 's suggestion. I did the fix as below and it work like a charm now.  I also removed the "system.web.extensions" portion away from my web.config

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void GetData(string login)
        {

            // when the amount of data return is huge
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            // we need to do this.
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;


            var result = serializer.Serialize(service.GetData(login));


            Context.Response.Write(result);
        }
```