# Can we set the jsonSerialization maxJsonLength value more than 2147483647?

Tags: asp.net, json.net, javascriptserializer

In web.config file we have set the

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647">
</jsonSerialization>`
```

However, we are receiving more data than the above-mentioned limit. 
Is there a way we can increase it beyond this limit? I'm aware of ways this be avoided (like pagination).

Following is the code that we are using for Serialize the data:

`jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(object1);`

are there places where maxJsonLength could be overridden from?

Comment: You're receiving more than 2GB worth of JSON!!!!!

Comment: May I suggest to compress data or change file format? as @phuzi say: that's a HUGE json file

Comment: I don't think I'm receiving 2GB of data. In that case, maybe this property is being overridden by something else.

Comment: Following is the code that I'm using for serializing the object                    
jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objec1);

Comment: `maxJsonLength` eventually becomes an [`int`-valued property of `JavaScriptSerializer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer_MaxJsonLength).  Now, `JavaScriptSerializer` doesn't have a method to parse directly from a stream!  It can only parse a string.  And in .Net the theoretical max length of a string is also 2,147,483,647, see [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140468).  So it can't be larger.

Comment: Oh, if you're parsing directly with your own instance of `JavaScriptSerializer`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207539): *The value of the MaxJsonLength property applies only to the internal JavaScriptSerializer instance that is used by the asynchronous communication layer to invoke Web services methods.*  You need to set it directly on the serializer instead.

Comment: Ah here we go, maybe a duplicate of [length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28239203).  Agree?

Comment: @dbc, I do not have this property setup anywhere else in my code or configs. Could this be an IIS or website default setting? I was actually thinking that there is no way I could have exhausted the 2GB limit for this.

Comment: @Prashant - In your question, you do `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(object1);`  The duplicate explains that you must manually set `MaxJsonLength` on the serializer, which you are not doing, e.g. `new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue }.Serialize(object1);`

Comment: @dbc, is there a way I could do this through a config file instead of hardcoding in the code?

Comment: @Prashant there is no documented way to do this.  See [`ScriptingJsonSerializationSection.MaxJsonLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.scriptingjsonserializationsection.maxjsonlength?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Configuration_ScriptingJsonSerializationSection_MaxJsonLength): *The value of the MaxJsonLength property applies only to the internal JavaScriptSerializer instance that is used by the asynchronous communication layer to invoke Web services methods.*  That is the essence of my suggested duplicate(s).

Answer (score 2):

No, the value is parsed as an integer (int 32) with a maximum value of [2147483647](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Setting anything above that will cause an error as you probably observed.